# Count frequency using generator in python

Tags: python-3.x, generator, counter

I built a generator that yields around 6 million dictionaries, and I want to count the frequency of a value in the dictionary.

For instance, each dictionary looks like below, and I want to count the value of the key `'state'`

```
dict1 = {'name':'Jane','state':'Alabama'}
dict2 = {'name':'Joe','state':'California'}
```

and I want the result

```
{'Alabama':1,'California:1}
```

I know that I can append the 'state' value in a list and the use `from collections import Counter`, but I don't want to save the values in a list because the generator yields around 6 million dictionaries.

Is there a way to count the frequency in this case? Or any other memory efficient way would be helpful.

For now, I think maybe one way is to return a dictionary where key is state and value is the count using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be straightforward. Assuming every yielded value contains the `state` key:

```
result = Counter(d["state"] for d in my_generator())
```

Comment: Hi this is great!! Do you think it's memory efficient?

Comment: Assuming the generator is, yes. It doesn't store all of the yielded items in a list, but process them one by one.